# Changing form of ODE's system solution (strange results?) [maple]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, maple, symbolic-computation

I'm having trouble with solving this system of ODE's using Maple software:

$\frac{2q(3q-1)}{\tau^2}f_{1,R}+2\frac{q}{\tau}\dot{f}_{1,R}+\ddot{f}_{1,R}+(\kappa^2+f_{2,T})(1+\omega)(\tau/\tau_0)^{(-3(3+\omega)q)}=0$

and
$\frac{(-30q^2+54q^3+4q)}{\tau^3}f_{1,R}+\frac{(-4q+24q^2)}{\tau^2}\dot{f}_{1,R}+\frac{11q}{\tau}\ddot{f}_{1,R}+\dddot{f}_{1,R}-3\omega(1+\omega)(\kappa^2+f_{2,T})\frac{q}{\tau}(\tau/\tau_0)^{-3(1+\omega)q}=0
$

They're equations from this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01910 (45 and 47)
With functions $f_{1,R}(\tau)$ and $f_{2,R}(\tau)$, ($\dot{f}=df/d\tau$) and where $q,\omega,\kappa,\tau_0$ are constants.

Solutions should be:

$f_{1,R}(\tau)=C_+\tau^{\mu_+}+C_-\tau^{\mu_=}+A\tau^{-9q+2}$

$f_{2,T}(\tau)=-A(\frac{69q^2-25q+2}{1+\omega})\tau_0^{-9q}(\tau/\tau_0)^{3\omega q}-\kappa^2$

where $C$'s and $A$ are integration constants 
and
$\mu{\pm}=\frac{-2q+1\pm\sqrt{-20q^2+4q+1}}{2}$;

Here, i listed my maple code ($\tau=t,\;\omega=w,\;f_{1,R}=f1(t)\;,f_{2,T}=f2(t)$:

> sysode := 2*q*(3*q-1)*f1(t)/t^2+2*q*(diff(f1(t), t))/t+diff(f1(t), t, t)+(kappa^2+f2(t))*(1+w)*(t/t0)^(-(3*(3+w))*q) = 0, (54*q^3-30*q^2+4*q)*f1(t)/t^3+(24*q^2-4*q)*(diff(f1(t), t))/t^2+11*q*(diff(f1(t), t, t))/t+diff(f1(t), t, t, t)-3*w*(1+w)*(kappa^2+f2(t))*q*(t/t0)^(-(3*(1+w))*q)/t = 0;
>
> simplify(dsolve([sysode], build))

However, my solutions are much more complicated than those listed above:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJj0e.png

So, there is my question.
How to get rid of hypergeom functions in these solutions ? (I have noticed that function $f1(t)=f_{1,r}(\tau)$ wouldve been correct when no hypergeom factor is present)

Comment: Was your purported Maple code entered into Maple as 1D Maple notation source (ie.plaintext)? If so then the code you've shown looks wrong. Eg. explicit multiplication * symbols are missing in several places. Note that brackets alone do not represent multiplication in plaintext Maple input, eg. `(1+w)(1+f1(t))` denotes function application and is not equal to the product `(1+w)*(1+f(t))`.

Comment: This forum cannot support Maple's 2D Input, so enter your complete Maple code formatted as plaintext. Use statement terminators. Use pre tags, say, to format as quoted text. If you used the Maple GUI then format it as 1D Maple notation plaintext (right-click to do so) before you copy and paste it.

Comment: Note also that this is a math forum, not a programming forum. For difficulties with Maple programming you can use sites stackoverflow or mapleprimes.

Comment: I've pasted  my 2d Maple input as 1d plaintext  and added missing *'s. I will also ask on mapleprimes. Thanks for comments

Comment: Why is there still an italic `q`, appearing as `q(t/t0)` ? Why isn't it preceded by a `*`? There are clearly more syntax problems to resolve here.

Comment: It's strange - when i edit my post i see all q sandwiched between *, but not on the preview.